# What should I do to import those modules correctly?

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, draw

I want to run this code in jupyter notebook but it gives me that error :
ImportError: **cannot import name 'document' from 'browser'** (C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\browser_*init*_.py)

What should I do ?

```
from browser import document, window

def sketch(p): 
    def setup():
        p.createCanvas(500, 500)
        p.stroke(p.color("blue"))
        p.line(10, 10, 100, 100)
          
    def draw():
        pass

    p.setup = setup
    p.draw = draw
      
myP5 = window.p5.new(sketch)
```

Comment: are you sure you are using the right library?

Comment: your code looks wrong, you havent imported p5, you are creating a function within a functiom im guessing you actually want to create a class and a function within the class. did you find the code example somewhere online? what are you trying to do?

Comment: The problem that it works in replit and I want to run this code in jupyter notebook (and it does not work ) https://replit.com/@DougWightman/Day-2-Drawing-Basics#main.py